# S3 Bucket Region - www. subdomain issue

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, bucket

I created a bucket for my root folder in the US Standard region but when I created my www. subdomain that could be redirected to the root folder I placed it in the Oregon region.

The redirect from the address bar is failing (I set it up using buckets>properties>redirect). AWS doesn't seem to allow this swapping between regions, so I deleted and tried to recreate the www. subdomain again, this time in the US Standard region, but it now gives the error, "A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again."

In short, is there a way to change the region, as AWS is apparently not allowing multiple buckets with the same name (even in separate regions)?  I am planning to redirect from the domain name I registered online using Route 53 anyway, so does this issue matter (as I won't use the 'http://example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com' or 'http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com' because I will hopefully be using 'example.com' or 'www.example.com'.

Thank you all for the help; I hope this post is specific enough.  Cheers from a first post.

Answer (score 2):

> AWS doesn't seem to allow this swapping between regions,

That's not correct.  A bucket configured for redirection does not care where it's redirecting to -- it can redirect to *any* web site, and the destination doesn't have to be another bucket...so this is a misdiagnosis of the problem you were/are experiencing.

> AWS is apparently not allowing multiple buckets with the same name (even in separate regions)?

Well... no:

> “The bucket namespace is global - just like domain names”
>
> — http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109#02

Only one bucket of a given name can exist within S3 at any point in time.  Because S3 is a massive distributed global system, it can take time (though it should typically only take a few minutes) before you can create the bucket again.  That's your conflict -- the deletion hasn't globally propagated.

> “After a bucket is deleted, the name becomes available to reuse, but the name might not be available for you to reuse for various reasons. For example, some other account could create a bucket with that name. Note, too, that it might take some time before the name can be reused.”
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Once you get it created, focus on fixing the redirect.  If you haven't yet configured the DNS in Route 53, then *that* would be the reason the redirect didn't work -- it can't redirect *to something* that isn't working.  S3 accomplishes this magic by sending a browser redirect -- which is why you can redirect *anywhere* -- it doesn't resolve the new bucket destination internally.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to redirect using `Redirect all requests to another host name` as long as you have `Static Website` enabled on the bucket where you are redirecting too.

No there's no way to change the region other than deleting the bucket in a region and recreating it in another region. Bucket names are unique across all of S3.

You can use Route 53 to create an alias for any bucket by adding a `CNAME` record that way `www.yoursite.com` maps to something like `http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Hope this helps.